# Delphi 2009 - clientdataset findnearest

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, dbgrid

I am having an issue with `clientdataset` and the `findnearest` method.

I am displaying a number of records in a `dbgrid` and utilizing the on title click to change the index and sort of the grid. I can also click on a column a second time to change the column from ascending to descending sort. Also, after I click on a column, I have a `Tedit` box that the user can enter data and the program utilizes the `findnearest` method to find the nearest match in the column that has been clicked. It does this for ascending or descending indexes.

My problem is, when the index is in descending sequence, the `findnearest` picks the record after the one that should have been selected.

Here is some data, one set of data is ascending order, the other is descending.

Ascending - Able, Arnold, Arney, Barney, Bubba

Descending - Bubba, Barney, Arney, Arnold, Able

When I search for "A" on the Ascending, the record pointer lands on Able.
When I search for "B" on the Descending, the record pointer lands on Arney.
My two examples are not theory, this is what is actually happening.

My questions is - in the descending order, why does it skip Bubba and Barney?  Please don't give me another example.  Please use my data if you are going to make an example.  Please give me an explanation why findnearst skips the first two records in the descending sequence that clearly start with a "B".

Comment: The answer isn't going to change, no matter how many times you change the sample data. It's the same whether you use `A, B, C` or `D, E, F`, or `W, Y, Z`, or `Fred, Barney, and Wilma`. It's the same problem, and the same answer, no matter how many ways you ask it. I explained it using your data, and instead of actually reading what I wrote (several times), you simply changed the data to bump the question.

Comment: @Owen - It's really simple: in descending order 'B' is "greater than" 'Bubba' and 'Barney'. That's why 'B' skips 'Bubba'.

Comment: Thanks Sertac, but isn't B less than Bubba?  Why when I look "Bu" does it land on Arney?

Comment: @Owen - No, 'B' is not less then 'Bubba'. Think about it the other way, 'Bu' is less then 'Bubba' in ascending order. Hence the opposite must be true in descending order.

Answer (score 3):

I can explain why this is the case (hopefully with some clarity) and why it's actually the proper behavior. (The following description will simply discuss single-byte characters for simplicity, but the answer should apply to others as well.)

Given the following data (I've intentionally made them slightly different for easier explanation - you'll see why below, I hope), let's presume we're at the top row (**A** for ascending order, and **Charlie** for descending) in both cases.

```
(Ascending)         (Descending)
LastName            LastName
========            ========
A                   Charlie
Abe                 Bob
Ada                 Ada
B                   Abe
Bob                 A
```

Starting from the first row (row **A**) in ascending order and searching for **Ac**, we'd encounter **Abe** first. It's not a match, and what we're looking for should be after it in ascending order, so we move on looking for **Ac**.

It's not there, and we're now at the row where where the match would have been found, which is the row immediately afterward (**Ada**). In other words, we're positioned at the place the match would have been if it were present (the *nearest row*).

Now let's say we search for **Al**. We're at **Ada**, so we move to the next row, and find there is no **Al**. We're now at **B**, where **Al** would have been found if it were present. In other words, we're at the *nearest row*. (This can be confirmed with a quick test.)

When we're in descending order, the examples work the same way. (Remember, I've made the data slightly different, to make it easier to explain.) Let's search for **Cecil**:

We're at the first row, **Charlie**, and move to the next row looking for **Ce** (which would be *after* **Charlie** in descending order, not before, as shown by **Abe** and **A** in the data above). We discover we don't have a match, and we're currently on row **Bob**, which is where **C** would have been found if it were present. In other words, in descending order we're at the **nearest row**, just like it worked in the ascending example.

So there's not a problem in `FindNearest`. If you want the behavior to be different, you have to implement it in your code (check to see if you've found an exact match, and if not move one row prior if needed, and check to see if it's where you want to be instead).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and it makes sense.  But on the descending data we might have:

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and it makes sense.  But on the descending data we might have:   Charlie, Chirly, Chosey, Cmmar, Bob, Ada, Abe A.  And when I search for a C it will point to Bob.  So it seems like it skips all he C's.

Comment: That's correct. It doesn't skip all C's. See my answer, the last three paragraphs. It explains exactly what happens when you search for "C" alone. "C" comes after "Charlie", so it would find "Charlie", move to the next row looking for "C" alone, and not find it. Therefore, we're on *the nearest row*, just like I explained above. The **exact behavior** and reasons for them are in my answer, and the solution to work around this behavior is in the last paragraph of that answer. The behavior is correct according to the rules of character collation (sorting).

Comment: Please follow the **exact sequence** I've provided twice now (once in my answer, and once in my last comment). I explained it **step by step** in both of them; I'm not sure how repeating it a third time will help, but I will - it *will be the last time I try*. It does not "skip all the 'C' values", because there **is no** 'C' value. There's 'Charlie', and when it moves past (lower in the grid) in descending order, there is no 'C', but **it's in the position 'C' would have been found in, so it has *found the nearest row* in descending sort order** - it's where it's supposed to be.

Comment: I keep explaining. Your confusion is in this sentence from your question: "the findnearest picks the record before the one that should have been selected.". No, it doesn't, because in *descending order* (C, B, A), **A comes *after* B, not *before* it**. You even stated it correctly as " Cats, Baker and Able." (note **C, B, A**, or **C comes before B which comes before A**).

Answer (score 1):

Okay I'll have a go.

Your basic problem is you are thinking FindNearest should "know" what order the items are in. 
i.e. the behaviour you want is when the list is in descending order you want FindNearest to start from the bottom of the list and work upwards.

It doesn't, it always works from the top, you can prove this quite easily by giving it an unordered list.

Comment: Good luck. I said that already: "Starting from the **first row** (row A)" in ascending order, and "We're at the **first row**, Charlie, and move to the next row looking for Ce". Hope you have better luck than I did. :-) In the deleted "answer" he posted, he even indicates he understands the behavior in ascending order ("if I type 'ac', it will land on baa. This works like it should."), but thinks the **exact same behavior** in descending order is wrong. I've explained it at least six times (the three above, and three more in comments left on the "answer" that's gone, all to no avail.

Comment: Thought I'd help you out, when I saw his own answer flagged as not an answer, which it wasn't.

Comment: I've spent two days repeating the same thing in different ways trying to get through, to no avail. I've drawn pictures, used smaller words, used different data to try to make it more clear... All I've gotten is a headache. No thanks, no upvote (from him), nada. Well, I did get a "With all due respect" before a veiled insult about my intellect, I guess. :-)

Comment: With all due respect, is a red flag, means said person does not have any for you. Its up there with "I know its none of my business but,..."

Comment: Yeah. :-) I knew when I saw it that I wasn't going to get anywhere (but tried twice more anyway). :-)

Answer (score 0):

In delphi findnearest method executes GotoNearest and GotoNearest according to delphi documentation;  positions the cursor on the record that is either the exact record specified by the current key values in the key buffer, **or on the first record whose values exceed those specified.**

This makes sense in ascending order, I have two records AU and BU and searching for B.  B is greater than AU but less than BU so it places the cursor on the first record whose values exceeds those specified - BU.

But in descending it works differently in terms of outcome.  If I have two records BU and AU in descending sequence, and I search for B,  the cursor lands on AU.  This is confusing to me.   BU is greater than B, so why not land on BU?

The reason;  The docuentation says that if there is not a match the cursor will be positioned on the first record whose value exeeed those specified.  But in fact what gotonearest does is perform a getnext.  So, in an ascending index, the getnext is a larger key, but in a descending index the getnext is a smaller key.

Comment: Your third paragraph is not accurate. You say that you have two records 'BU' and 'AU' in sequence. So you have no problem accepting the fact that 'AU' comes after (is greater than) 'BU'. But you don't seem to be able to accept the fact that 'B' is always between 'AU' and 'BU'. If you had an additional 'B' record, your sequence would be 'BU', 'B', 'AU' (insert a record and see for yourself). That means *'BU' is greater than 'B'* is wrong, which also invalidates *" in descending it works differently"*.

Comment: It does not work differently, it works exactly the same . Findnearest doesn't know anything about the  orderedness of the items. Which is the point we are all trying to make and you seem to have a real problem with. Try it with an unordered list!

Comment: Sertac, I accept that B is between AU and BU.  Ascending sequence AU B BU.  Descending sequence BU B AU.   When I say works differently, I mean outcome not internals.  Yes, internal is the same but outcome, searching for B in a descending sequence versus ascending will net a different result.  So, in an ascending index, the getnext is a larger key, but in a descending index the getnext is a smaller key. Result is different, yes it works the same with the getnext.

Comment: Tony, different outcome, not different internals.  
The findnearest that I am using does know about order.  I am using a clientdataset.  My delphi will not let me run a findnearest unless I set an index.  I have never seen an index as an unordered set.  If find nearest runs with an unordered set, great, I have not done it.  I am dealing with clientdatasets and indexes.